# How do I use base64 encoding with loadproperties in Ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ant, base64

I have content in a properties file encoded in base64 (there are passwords in it that I just want to be not plain text). When I create a loadproperties task in Ant like this:

```
<loadproperties srcFile="mypasswords.properties" encoding="base64" />
```

and then try to run any target in the build.xml, I get an error like so:

```
/path/to/build.xml:10: Unable to load file: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: base64
```

I've looked and looked for what could be wrong. Am I using the wrong string for the encoding attribute? Am I missing a jar?

I'm on OS X 10.6.8, Eclipse Indigo, Ant 1.8.2, JRE 1.6.0_31

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the **encoding** parameter of the [loadproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) task refers the file character encoding, not encoding applied to property values.

Instead of encoding I would suggest encrypting your passwords, an example is contained in the following answer:

[Where do I put my credentials when using Ivy and a private company repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503630/where-do-i-put-my-credentials-when-using-ivy-and-a-private-company-repository/7505364#7505364)