# Custom property handling with ant

Tags: java, ant

We have a properties file (e.g. `db.properties`) that contains the credentials for a database access. Example:

```
db.jdbc.user=johndoe 
db.jdbc.password=topsecret
```

We have many ant scripts that read this file and execute various tasks. Example:

```
<!--Initialize the environment-->
<target name="environment">

<!--Read database connection properties-->
    <property file="$../db.properties"/>
    ...
</target>

<target name="dbping"
    description="Test the database connectivity with the current settings."
    depends="environment">
    ...
    <sql driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         url="${db.jdbc.url}"
         userid="${db.jdbc.user}"
         password="${db.jdbc.password}"
         classpathref="classpath.jdbc"
         print="true"
         showheaders="false">
         SELECT 'JDBC connect: successful!' FROM dual;
    </sql>

    ...
</target>
```

Now the client wants that the password in the db.properties is encrypted by using their encryption lib provided within a .jar file, e.g.:

```
db.jdbc.user=johndoe
db.jdbc.password.encrypted=true
db.jdbc.password=018Dal0AdnE=|ySHZl0FsnYOvM+114Q1hNA==
```

What we want to is to achieve the decryption with minimum modifications of the tons of ant files. I've heard about the enhanced property handling in `Ant 1.8`, but we use `Ant 1.7.1`.

What is the best solution for this - custom task, some magic with the `PropertyHelper` instance, something else?

Thanks in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I preferred is to handle the problem with my own custom task. This required minimum changes. In our ant script this task looks like this:

```
<!--Initialize the environment-->
<target name="environment">

    <!--Read database connection properties-->
    <property file="$../db.properties"/>
    ...

    <decryptpwd passwordProperty="db.jdbc.password"/>

</target>
```

The task is also trivial. It looks like this:

```
public class DecryptPassword extends Task
{
    @Override
    public void execute()
    {
        ...
        PropertyHelper.getPropertyHelper(getProject()).setProperty(null, passwordProperty, getDecryptedPassword(),
                            false);
        ...                 
    }
}
```

And yeap - it seems to work ;-)

Comment: See this answer for similar approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503630/where-do-i-put-my-credentials-when-using-ivy-and-a-private-company-repository/7505364#7505364

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you want to take is the wrapper approach that you can do within ant.

parent ant script:

```
<target name="decrypt">    
  <exec executable="myJar">
    <arg value="encryptedString"/>
  </exec>
</target>  
    <target name="build-foo">
        <subant target="build">
          <fileset dir="${test.home}" includes="Foobuild.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>

    <target name="build-bar">
        <subant target="build">
          <fileset dir="${test.home}" includes="Barbuild.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
```

use [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html)
and [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)  (**POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS**)

What you want to do is drop each of your subscripts into this parent build file and pass around the unencrypted String to each of the scripts as a parameter / read in from a property.

Comment: Thanks! All these subscripts are self sufficient units that only depend on a target which sets some environmental variables. They test the connectivity to the db, import, export, etc. I would currently prefer my own custom task which I'll put into the environment target. This task will decrypt the password and using the PropertyHelper will provide a decrypted version for the other targets.