# Is there any ant task to decrypt passwords?

Tags: ant

I am trying to establish connection to Oracle Database using ant scripts. All the connection parameters I am reading from my db.properties. But the password is encrypted. Is there ant task to decrypt the password without writing any java class.

Comment: encrypted how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Why don't you write your own properties file with the settings copied from your db.properties and change the password to plane text? Otherwise it would be good to know which algorithm  is used to encrypt the password.

Answer (score 0):

See [Custom property handling with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791567/custom-property-handling-with-ant) for encrypting/decrypting passwords in Ant. However, it works with Java classes.

In any case, you will need an external tool to encrypt/decrypt your password. You can use something different than Java classes. If you want to do so, you can use the Ant `exec` task to run an external tool for encrypting/decrypting (e.g., a .bat file, an .exe file etc.):

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

But be aware that the communication between Ant and the external tool will not be safe.