# Masking(hiding) password in ant xml file

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have ant file with many variables having password values hardcoded, so basically anyone having access to that file can see all the passwords and usernames. I want to know if there is any way to hide the hardcoded password from .xml? Thank for the help in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503630/where-do-i-put-my-credentials-when-using-ivy-and-a-private-company-repository/7505364#7505364

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can restrict the permissions of the file to the user that actually executes the application. This will restrict the file to a select number of users.

Answer (score 0):

Well presumably you don't actually *need* to store the password, you just need a hash you can test against. Make sure it's salted (and the salt isn't stored in the file) and the file itself has the proper rights (ie as few people as possible have access to it) and that's pretty much all you can do.