# How to enrich "GrabResolver" with Login Credentials

Tags: groovy, maven-2, nexus3

I'm trying to retrieve an Artefact from our internal Nexus OSS Maven Repository with Groovy's "GrabResolver" Annotation with the following Statement:

```
@GrabResolver(name = 'bla', root = 'http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/bla/', m2Compatible = 'true')
....
groovy.grape.Grape.grab(group: '...', module: '...', version: '...', ext: '...')
```

Now I'm facing the Problem that our Nexus is secured with Login Credentials and does not show up artefacts for anonymous access.

Is it possible to pass the Login Credentials to the GrabResolver Call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to add credentials from the annotation. You can [customize your Ivy settings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-CustomizeIvysettings) to do it for you. [Add your credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503630/where-do-i-put-my-credentials-when-using-ivy-and-a-private-company-repository?noredirect=1&lq=1) to ~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml

Comment: can u share complete xml file.I am having error