# Groovy script fails to install grapes from remote Secure maven repository

Tags: groovy, maven-2, ivy, github-package-registry, groovy-grape

Thanks for taking the time to read!

I am attempting to configure my grapeConfig (ivysettings) file to utilize a remote maven repository (github Packages) for grape installations while writing groovy scripts. For a specific questions, what from my config outlined below could be the problem preventing my credentials from being properly provided causing a 401 access  error?

I am attempting to follow the instructions provided  here (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-CustomizeIvysettings) and here (https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/credentials.html)

And several other posts like the following where they instruct to use the credentials tag similar to the documentation provided by apache.

[How to enrich "GrabResolver" with Login Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300697/how-to-enrich-grabresolver-with-login-credentials)

[Where do I put my credentials when using Ivy and a private company repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503630/where-do-i-put-my-credentials-when-using-ivy-and-a-private-company-repository?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but when my script attempts to download the grapes i receive a 401.

For "TLDR" I am receieving a 401 from the remote repository
"**authentication: k='GitHub Package Registry@maven.pkg.github.com' c='null'**
HTTP response status: 401 url=https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>///0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml"

i think my access problem is due to the line above shown from the debug statements.
the "authentication:" has a parameter "K" set to what seems to be the realm and the variable "c" seems to be set to null. I am wondering if there is some misconfiguration in the way that the repositories credentials are being provided causing the 401.

Here is my configuration.

```
<ivysettings>
    <property name="repo.pass" value="<git-hub-token>"  override="false"/>   
    <property name="repo.user" value="<github-user>"  override="false"/>    
    <property name="repo.realm" value="GitHub Package Registry" override="false"/>        
    <credentials host="https://maven.pkg.github.com" realm="${repo.realm}" username="${repo.user}" passwd="${repo.pass}"/>
    <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="downloadGrapes" returnFirst="true">
            <ibiblio name="gitHub" root="https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>" m2compatible="true" />
            <ibiblio name="localm2" root="${user.home.url}/.m2/repository/" checkmodified="true" changingPattern=".*" changingMatcher="regexp" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false"/>
            <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="mirror" root="http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

If i happen to build the artifact that i am trying to pull from the remote repository locally (mvn install ) then i can resolve the dependency based on my "localm2" ibiblio.

while running the script with debug i can see that the settings i provided and the credentials i provided are detected and output.
groovy -Divy.message.logger.level=4 test.groovy

---- snipit from debug output.

```
    setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Groovy/lib/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
    setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Users\<user>\IdeaProjects\homework\groovy\src\.'
    setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Groovy/lib/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
    .....
    setting 'ivy.build.artifacts.dir' to '${ivy.project.dir}/build/artifacts'
    setting 'ivy.lib.dir' to '${ivy.project.dir}/lib'
    setting 'ivy.cache.ttl.default' to '10s'
    setting 'ivy.buildlist.ivyfilepath' to 'ivy.xml'
    setting 'ivy.distrib.dir' to '${ivy.project.dir}/distrib'
    setting 'repo.pass' to '<git-hub-token>'
    setting 'repo.user' to '<git-hub-user>'
    setting 'repo.realm' to 'GitHub Package Registry'
    credentials added: GitHub Package Registry@https://maven.pkg.github.com <username>/****************************************
    
    ......
    
    
    settings loaded (208ms)
        default cache: C:\Users\<user>\.ivy2\cache
        default resolver: downloadGrapes
        default latest strategy: latest-revision
        default conflict manager: latest-revision
        circular dependency strategy: warn
        validate: true
        check up2date: true
        -- 5 resolvers:
        downloadGrapes [chain] [gitHub, localm2, ibiblio, mirror]
            return first: true
            dual: false
            -> gitHub
            -> localm2
            -> ibiblio
            -> mirror
        mirror [ibiblio]
            cache: null
            m2compatible: true
            ivy patterns:
                http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            artifact patterns:
                http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            repository: mirror
            root: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/
            pattern: [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            usepoms: true
            useMavenMetadata: true
        gitHub [ibiblio]
            cache: null
            m2compatible: true
            ivy patterns:
                https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            artifact patterns:
                https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            repository: gitHub
            root: https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/
            pattern: [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            usepoms: true
            useMavenMetadata: true
        localm2 [ibiblio]
            cache: null
            m2compatible: true
            ivy patterns:
            artifact patterns:
                file:/C:/Users/<user>//.m2/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            repository: localm2
            root: file:/C:/Users/<user>//.m2/repository/
            pattern: [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            usepoms: false
            useMavenMetadata: true
        ibiblio [ibiblio]
            cache: null
            m2compatible: true
            ivy patterns:
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            artifact patterns:
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            repository: ibiblio
            root: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
            pattern: [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
            usepoms: true
            useMavenMetadata: true
        module settings:
            NONE
    
   

     == resolving dependencies caller#all-caller;working52-><group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [default->default]
        loadData of <group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT of rootConf=default
            using downloadGrapes to resolve <group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: <group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT {default=[default]}
            no ivy file in cache for <group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: tried C:\Users\<user>\.groovy\grapes\<group>\<artifactid>\ivy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml
        don't use cache for <group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
        try to get credentials for: GitHub Package Registry@maven.pkg.github.com
        authentication: k='GitHub Package Registry@maven.pkg.github.com' c='null'
        HTTP response status: 401 url=https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/<group>/<artifactId>/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
        CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/<group>/<artifactId>/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
            maven-metadata not available for: <group>#<artifactId>;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
             trying https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/<group>/<artifactId>/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/<artifactId>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
                tried https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/<group>/<artifactId>/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/<artifactId>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
        try to get credentials for: GitHub Package Registry@maven.pkg.github.com
        authentication: k='GitHub Package Registry@maven.pkg.github.com' c='null'
```

The portion from the above that I am concerned about is the following.

```
        authentication: k='GitHub Package Registry@maven.pkg.github.com' c='null'
        HTTP response status: 401 url=https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/<group>/<artifactId>/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
        CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=https://maven.pkg.github.com/<github-organization/repository>/<group>/<artifactId>/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

the "authentication:" has a parameter "K" set to what seems to be the realm" and the variable "c" seems to be set to null. I am wondering if there is some miss configuration in the way that the repositories credentials are being provided causing the 401.

I have verified my access to this remote repository by creating a separate maven project whos settings.xml are configured with the credentials i have provided in the ivySettings above. With this separate maven project when i conduct a build i can see the artifact being installed in my local m2.

I am assuming that there must something im doing incorrectly while providing the credentials. I do have an alternate solution if i cant get this solved, i will turn the project running the groovy script into a maven project utilizing a maven package to install the jars into my localm2 then allowing the ivyConfig to pull them from there.

Thanks for reading!